# Computer Beeps Randomly since Few Days - Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: boot, 16.04, sound

so I have this weird event happening **since few days** on my computer:   usually it happens **during booting 1 or 2 times**, but it also happend **when I am using my computer**, sometimes it just make a **short beep randomly.**
I know **usually beeps mean something**, but I have no expertise about it, when beeps just happen randomly in Ubuntu 16.04.
So far I haven't been able to identify the source of the problem, but I would really enjoy to learn more about this event if you could help me identify the problem!
So far `smartctl` did not show any problem on my HDDs. I also checked the temperature of my CPU cores with `sensors`, they were all at 40°C when the beeps happen.

Here is what I have been able to catch right after 1 beep with `dmesg | tail -50`:

```
[   19.347057] input: HDA Intel PCH Line as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1b.0/sound/card0/input13
[   19.347094] input: HDA Intel PCH Line Out as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1b.0/sound/card0/input14
[   19.347131] input: HDA Intel PCH Front Headphone as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1b.0/sound/card0/input15
[   20.293817] intel_rapl: Found RAPL domain package
[   20.293820] intel_rapl: Found RAPL domain core
[   20.293823] intel_rapl: Found RAPL domain dram
[   20.293827] intel_rapl: RAPL package 0 domain package locked by BIOS
[   20.293830] intel_rapl: RAPL package 0 domain dram locked by BIOS
[   20.377520] input: HDA NVidia HDMI/DP,pcm=3 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.0/0000:01:00.1/sound/card2/input16
[   20.377567] input: HDA NVidia HDMI/DP,pcm=7 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.0/0000:01:00.1/sound/card2/input17
[   20.599901] usb 3-2: set resolution quirk: cval->res = 384
[   20.600016] uvcvideo: Found UVC 1.00 device <unnamed> (046d:0825)
[   20.600018] usbcore: registered new interface driver snd-usb-audio
[   20.614568] input: UVC Camera (046d:0825) as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-2/3-2:1.0/input/input18
[   20.614620] usbcore: registered new interface driver uvcvideo
[   20.614621] USB Video Class driver (1.1.1)
[   33.301051] audit: type=1400 audit(1567057095.131:2): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="/sbin/dhclient" pid=844 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   33.301057] audit: type=1400 audit(1567057095.131:3): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/lib/NetworkManager/nm-dhcp-client.action" pid=844 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   33.301061] audit: type=1400 audit(1567057095.131:4): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/lib/NetworkManager/nm-dhcp-helper" pid=844 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   33.301065] audit: type=1400 audit(1567057095.131:5): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/lib/connman/scripts/dhclient-script" pid=844 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   33.301824] audit: type=1400 audit(1567057095.131:6): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/lib/lightdm/lightdm-guest-session" pid=843 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   33.301830] audit: type=1400 audit(1567057095.131:7): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/lib/lightdm/lightdm-guest-session//chromium" pid=843 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   33.302868] audit: type=1400 audit(1567057095.131:8): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="/snap/core/5145/usr/lib/snapd/snap-confine" pid=845 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   33.302874] audit: type=1400 audit(1567057095.131:9): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="/snap/core/5145/usr/lib/snapd/snap-confine//mount-namespace-capture-helper" pid=845 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   33.352779] audit: type=1400 audit(1567057095.183:10): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/bin/evince" pid=846 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   33.352787] audit: type=1400 audit(1567057095.183:11): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/bin/evince//sanitized_helper" pid=846 comm="apparmor_parser"
[  105.895384] usb 3-2: reset high-speed USB device number 3 using xhci_hcd
[  106.563625] Process accounting resumed
[  108.001839] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): enp3s0: link is not ready
[  108.181170] r8169 0000:03:00.0 enp3s0: link down
[  108.181199] r8169 0000:03:00.0 enp3s0: link down
[  108.181250] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): enp3s0: link is not ready
[  109.223080] audit_printk_skb: 69 callbacks suppressed
[  109.223082] audit: type=1400 audit(1567057171.059:35): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="/usr/sbin/mysqld" name="/proc/1184/status" pid=1184 comm="mysqld" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=121 ouid=121
[  109.223109] audit: type=1400 audit(1567057171.059:36): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="/usr/sbin/mysqld" name="/sys/devices/system/node/" pid=1184 comm="mysqld" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=121 ouid=0
[  109.223141] audit: type=1400 audit(1567057171.059:37): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="/usr/sbin/mysqld" name="/proc/1184/status" pid=1184 comm="mysqld" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=121 ouid=121
[  109.753759] r8169 0000:03:00.0 enp3s0: link up
[  109.753769] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): enp3s0: link becomes ready
[  125.945999] usb 3-2: reset high-speed USB device number 3 using xhci_hcd
[16322.327003] usb 3-2: reset high-speed USB device number 3 using xhci_hcd
[16442.390730] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: Direct firmware load for nouveau/nvd9_fuc084 failed with error -2
[16442.390745] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: Direct firmware load for nouveau/nvd9_fuc084d failed with error -2
[16442.390748] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: msvld: unable to load firmware data
[16442.390751] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: msvld: init failed, -19
[21469.507282] perf interrupt took too long (2506 > 2500), lowering kernel.perf_event_max_sample_rate to 50000
[22041.696418] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: Direct firmware load for nouveau/nvd9_fuc084 failed with error -2
[22041.696426] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: Direct firmware load for nouveau/nvd9_fuc084d failed with error -2
[22041.696429] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: msvld: unable to load firmware data
[22041.696431] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: msvld: init failed, -19
[23200.601584] usb 3-2: reset high-speed USB device number 3 using xhci_hcd
```

And this is what I got from `lsmod | grep pc`:

```
crct10dif_pclmul       16384  0
crc32_pclmul           16384  0
snd_pcm               106496  5 snd_usb_audio,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_core
snd_timer              32768  2 snd_pcm,snd_seq
snd                    86016  25 snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_usb_audio,snd_hwdep,snd_timer,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_pcm,snd_seq,snd_rawmidi,snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_usbmidi_lib,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_intel,snd_seq_device
shpchp                 36864  0
lpc_ich                24576  0
parport_pc             32768  0
parport                49152  3 lp,ppdev,parport_pc
```

I decided to show this output because someone was asking for it in a similar post I found on the web.
Feel free to ask whatever is necessary so that I found where does the problem come from.

EDIT: here is the result of the command `cat /proc/cpuinfo | grep "model name"`:

```
model name  : Intel(R) [Pentium(R) CPU G3220][1] @ 3.00GHz
```

It looks like `sudo lshw | grep -A5 "Moth" && lshw | grep product | head -n1`  is not returning anything. When I enter this part alone, it shortly display `PCI (sysfs)` then `USB` in the terminal but doesn't print anything.

EDIT 2: Here are the information about Motherboard, CPU, and some peripherics. I replace sensible information by `■`.

```
*-core
       description: Carte mère
       produit: imedia L4880
       fabriquant: Packard Bell
       identifiant matériel: 0
       numéro de série: ■
     *-firmware
          description: BIOS
          fabriquant: American Megatrends Inc.
          identifiant matériel: 0
          version: P11-A2
          date: 11/08/2013
          taille: 64KiB
          capacité: 4032KiB
          fonctionnalités: pci apm upgrade shadowing cdboot bootselect socketedrom edd int13floppy1200 int13floppy720 int13floppy2880 int5printscreen int9keyboard int14serial int17printer acpi usb biosbootspecification uefi
     *-cpu
          description: CPU
          produit: Intel(R) Pentium(R) CPU G3220 @ 3.00GHz
          fabriquant: Intel Corp.
          identifiant matériel: 1b
          information bus: cpu@0
          version: Intel(R) Pentium(R) CPU G3220 @ 3.00GHz
          emplacement: LGA1150
          taille: 2973MHz
          capacité: 3GHz
          bits: 64 bits
          horloge: 100MHz
          fonctionnalités: x86-64 fpu fpu_exception wp vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe syscall nx pdpe1gb rdtscp constant_tsc arch_perfmon pebs bts rep_good nopl xtopology nonstop_tsc aperfmperf pni pclmulqdq dtes64 monitor ds_cpl vmx est tm2 ssse3 sdbg cx16 xtpr pdcm pcid sse4_1 sse4_2 movbe popcnt tsc_deadline_timer xsave rdrand lahf_lm abm epb invpcid_single ssbd ibrs ibpb stibp pti tpr_shadow vnmi flexpriority ept vpid fsgsbase tsc_adjust erms invpcid xsaveopt dtherm arat pln pts md_clear flush_l1d cpufreq
          configuration: cores=2 enabledcores=2 threads=2

*-usb:0
     description: USB controller
     produit: 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family USB xHCI
     fabriquant: Intel Corporation
     identifiant matériel: 14
     information bus: pci@0000:00:14.0
     version: 05
     bits: 64 bits
     horloge: 33MHz
     fonctionnalités: pm msi xhci bus_master cap_list
     configuration: driver=xhci_hcd latency=0
     ressources: irq:27 mémoire:f7200000-f720ffff
   *-usbhost:0
        produit: xHCI Host Controller
        fabriquant: Linux 4.4.0-159-generic xhci-hcd
        identifiant matériel: 0
        information bus: usb@4
        nom logique: usb4
        version: 4.04
        fonctionnalités: usb-3.00
        configuration: driver=hub slots=2 speed=5000Mbit/s
   *-usbhost:1
        produit: xHCI Host Controller
        fabriquant: Linux 4.4.0-159-generic xhci-hcd
        identifiant matériel: 1
        information bus: usb@3
        nom logique: usb3
        version: 4.04
        fonctionnalités: usb-2.00
        configuration: driver=hub slots=10 speed=480Mbit/s
      *-usb:0
           description: Clavier
           produit: USB wired keyboard
           fabriquant: Liteon Technology Corp.
           identifiant matériel: 1
           information bus: usb@3:1
           version: 1.01
           fonctionnalités: usb-2.00
           configuration: driver=usbhid maxpower=100mA speed=1Mbit/s
      *-usb:1
           description: Vidéo
           produit: Webcam C270
           fabriquant: Logitech, Inc.
           identifiant matériel: 2
           information bus: usb@3:2
           version: 0.12
           numéro de série: ■
           fonctionnalités: usb-2.00
           configuration: driver=snd-usb-audio maxpower=500mA speed=480Mbit/s
      *-usb:2
           description: Souris
           produit: Gaming mouse
           fabriquant: Mosart
           identifiant matériel: 3
           information bus: usb@3:3
           version: 0.29
           fonctionnalités: usb-2.00
           configuration: driver=usbhid maxpower=500mA speed=12Mbit/s
      *-usb:3
           description: Concentrateur USB
           produit: USB 2.0 Hub
           fabriquant: Terminus Technology Inc.
           identifiant matériel: 6
           information bus: usb@3:6
           version: 1.11
           fonctionnalités: usb-2.00
           configuration: driver=hub maxpower=100mA slots=4 speed=480Mbit/s
         *-usb:0
              description: Périphérique de stockage de masse
              produit: My Passport 25E2
              fabriquant: Western Digital
              identifiant matériel: 1
              information bus: usb@3:6.1
              nom logique: scsi4
              version: 40.05
              numéro de série: ■
              fonctionnalités: usb-2.10 scsi emulated scsi-host
              configuration: driver=usb-storage maxpower=500mA speed=480Mbit/s
            *-disk
                 description: SCSI Disk
                 produit: My Passport 25E2
                 fabriquant: WD
                 identifiant matériel: 0.0.0
                 information bus: scsi@4:0.0.0
                 nom logique: /dev/sdb
                 version: 4005
                 numéro de série: ■
                 taille: 3725GiB (4TB)
                 fonctionnalités: gpt-1.00 partitioned partitioned:gpt
                 configuration: ansiversion=6 guid=b456bc3d-c336-4452-b06c-b874c0a1656d logicalsectorsize=512 sectorsize=4096
               *-volume
                    description: Windows NTFS volume
                    fabriquant: Windows
                    identifiant matériel: 1
                    information bus: scsi@4:0.0.0,1
                    nom logique: /dev/sdb1
                    nom logique: ■
                    version: 3.1
                    numéro de série: ■
                    taille: 1677GiB
                    capacité: 3725GiB
                    fonctionnalités: ntfs initialized
                    configuration: clustersize=4096 created=2019-06-01 15:11:55 filesystem=ntfs label=■ mount.fstype=fuseblk mount.options=rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,user_id=0,group_id=0,default_permissions,allow_other,blksize=4096 state=mounted
            *-enclosure NON-RÉCLAMÉ
                 description: SCSI Enclosure
                 produit: SES Device
                 fabriquant: WD
                 identifiant matériel: 0.0.1
                 information bus: scsi@4:0.0.1
                 version: 4005
                 numéro de série: ■
                 configuration: ansiversion=6
         *-usb:1
              description: Clavier
              produit: UltraMouse
              fabriquant: Mosart
              identifiant matériel: 2
              information bus: usb@3:6.2
              version: 0.03
              fonctionnalités: usb-1.00
              configuration: driver=usbhid maxpower=500mA speed=12Mbit/s
         *-usb:2
              description: Périphérique de stockage de masse
              produit: Elements 25A1
              fabriquant: Western Digital
              identifiant matériel: 3
              information bus: usb@3:6.3
              nom logique: scsi6
              version: 10.14
              numéro de série: ■
              fonctionnalités: usb-2.10 scsi emulated scsi-host
              configuration: driver=usb-storage maxpower=500mA speed=480Mbit/s
            *-disk
                 description: SCSI Disk
                 produit: Elements 25A1
                 fabriquant: WD
                 identifiant matériel: 0.0.0
                 information bus: scsi@6:0.0.0
                 nom logique: /dev/sdd
                 version: 1014
                 numéro de série: ■
                 taille: 3725GiB (4TB)
                 fonctionnalités: gpt-1.00 partitioned partitioned:gpt
                 configuration: ansiversion=6 guid=5b1cfa45-45c7-45f7-b9c1-286f9e7df28c logicalsectorsize=512 sectorsize=4096
               *-volume
                    description: Windows NTFS volume
                    fabriquant: Windows
                    identifiant matériel: 1
                    information bus: scsi@6:0.0.0,1
                    nom logique: /dev/sdd1
                    nom logique: ■
                    version: 3.1
                    numéro de série: ■
                    taille: 1677GiB
                    capacité: 3725GiB
                    fonctionnalités: ntfs initialized
                    configuration: clustersize=4096 created=2018-08-10 17:42:38 filesystem=ntfs label=Disque Dur 2 modified_by_chkdsk=true mount.fstype=fuseblk mount.options=rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,user_id=0,group_id=0,default_permissions,allow_other,blksize=4096 mounted_on_nt4=true name=Elements resize_log_file=true state=mounted upgrade_on_mount=true
         *-usb:3
              description: Périphérique de stockage de masse
              produit: My Passport 259D
              fabriquant: Western Digital
              identifiant matériel: 4
              information bus: usb@3:6.4
              nom logique: scsi7
              version: 10.12
              numéro de série: ■
              fonctionnalités: usb-2.10 scsi emulated scsi-host
              configuration: driver=usb-storage maxpower=500mA speed=480Mbit/s
            *-disk
                 description: SCSI Disk
                 produit: My Passport 259D
                 fabriquant: WD
                 identifiant matériel: 0.0.0
                 information bus: scsi@7:0.0.0
                 nom logique: /dev/sde
                 version: 1012
                 numéro de série: ■
                 taille: 3725GiB (4TB)
                 fonctionnalités: gpt-1.00 partitioned partitioned:gpt
                 configuration: ansiversion=6 guid=21687f04-9277-473a-917a-12e93cc1d154 logicalsectorsize=512 sectorsize=4096
               *-volume
                    description: Windows NTFS volume
                    fabriquant: Windows
                    identifiant matériel: 1
                    information bus: scsi@7:0.0.0,1
                    nom logique: /dev/sde1
                    nom logique: ■
                    version: 3.1
                    numéro de série: ■
                    taille: 1677GiB
                    capacité: 3725GiB
                    fonctionnalités: ntfs initialized
                    configuration: clustersize=4096 created=2016-12-29 10:02:43 filesystem=ntfs label=Disque Dur 1 modified_by_chkdsk=true mount.fstype=fuseblk mount.options=rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,user_id=0,group_id=0,default_permissions,allow_other,blksize=4096 mounted_on_nt4=true name=My Passport resize_log_file=true state=mounted upgrade_on_mount=true
            *-enclosure NON-RÉCLAMÉ
                 description: SCSI Enclosure
                 produit: SES Device
                 fabriquant: WD
                 identifiant matériel: 0.0.1
                 information bus: scsi@7:0.0.1
                 version: 1012
                 numéro de série: WX21D76F7CAZ
                 configuration: ansiversion=6
      *-usb:4
           description: Périphérique USB générique
           produit: USB2.0-CRW
           fabriquant: Generic
           identifiant matériel: 8
           information bus: usb@3:8
           version: 39.60
           numéro de série: ■
           fonctionnalités: usb-2.00
           configuration: driver=rtsx_usb maxpower=500mA speed=480Mbit/s
      *-usb:5
           description: Périphérique USB générique
           produit: ■
           fabriquant: ■
           identifiant matériel: 9
           information bus: usb@3:9
           version: 2.32
           numéro de série: ■
           fonctionnalités: usb-2.10
           configuration: driver=usbfs maxpower=500mA speed=480Mbit/s
*-communication
     description: Communication controller
     produit: 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family MEI Controller #1
     fabriquant: Intel Corporation
     identifiant matériel: 16
     information bus: pci@0000:00:16.0
     version: 04
     bits: 64 bits
     horloge: 33MHz
     fonctionnalités: pm msi bus_master cap_list
     configuration: driver=mei_me latency=0
     ressources: irq:31 mémoire:f721a000-f721a00f
*-usb:1
     description: USB controller
     produit: 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family USB EHCI #2
     fabriquant: Intel Corporation
     identifiant matériel: 1a
     information bus: pci@0000:00:1a.0
     version: 05
     bits: 32 bits
     horloge: 33MHz
     fonctionnalités: pm debug ehci bus_master cap_list
     configuration: driver=ehci-pci latency=0
     ressources: irq:16 mémoire:f7218000-f72183ff
   *-usbhost
        produit: EHCI Host Controller
        fabriquant: Linux 4.4.0-159-generic ehci_hcd
        identifiant matériel: 1
        information bus: usb@1
        nom logique: usb1
        version: 4.04
        fonctionnalités: usb-2.00
        configuration: driver=hub slots=2 speed=480Mbit/s
      *-usb
           description: Concentrateur USB
           fabriquant: Intel Corp.
           identifiant matériel: 1
           information bus: usb@1:1
           version: 0.05
           fonctionnalités: usb-2.00
           configuration: driver=hub slots=4 speed=480Mbit/s
```

Comment: @K7AAY Hi, I added the part you requested at the bottom of the issue. I think one part of the command doesn't work. The link to editing tips doesn't work so I just did it the way I felt. Let me know if you need something else.

Comment: @K7AAY : Hi, I went through the dsmeg and realize that this message : "reset high-speed USB device number 3 using xhci_hcd" is not a good sign. I found also this topic about on Superuser, comments are interesting because the guy is having a similar configuration with WD external hard drives and get the same message https://superuser.com/questions/668911/what-are-usb-device-resets . Now I am wondering if this beep is not link to the use of these external hard drive when they are all running at the same time on the same USB port... What do you think ?

Comment: @K7AAY I am sorry but I cannot post output of "sudo lshw && lshw | grep product | head -n1" : Askubuntu doesn't allow me to post more than 30 000 character for the body of the issue... I just added motherboard, CPU and drives models infos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I actually still haven't figured out yet the entire explanation for this event but here are some things I can already tell as a temporary answer:

The problem seems to come, indeed, from the fact that I have an adapter allowing me to plug 3 external hard drives on the same USB port. Consequently this message is displayed sometimes in dsmeg when a beep occurs: `usb 3-2: reset high-speed USB device number 3 using xhci_hcd`

Coming from a similar issue on SuperUser, a guy described the same message in dsmeg, happening with a very similar setup to mine, but do not say anything about the computer beeping: [superuser.com/questions/668911/what-are-usb-device-resets](http://superuser.com/questions/668911/what-are-usb-device-resets)

Since I completed the original issue posted, I also changed the configuration of how I plug my external hard drives: after using another USB port the random beeping did not occured anymore, either randomly, or during booting.

I don't have any proof currently, but my guess is that pluging 3 external hard drives on a single USB port is asking for a lot more energy than pluging just one of them, putting consequently under a higher tension motherboard parts that should not experience this... and that might explain the random short beeping when disks are used.

Comment: Oh, absolutement! If your USB port is true USB3 (blue or red connector), it provides a maximum of 900 ma; 500 ma if USB2. https://superuser.com/a/690077/264083